# convert List from JSON element to ArrayList using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, arraylist

I have a JSON object in session :

> { "Zone" : "Bangalore" , "Role" : "1" , "Vehicles" : [ "v123" , "v345"
>   , "v567"]}

I need to get the values of Vehicles in ArrayList and pass to a selectBox with multiple option

Am trying something like this:

```
 var temp = sessionStorage.getItem('userDetails');
    var viewName = $.parseJSON(temp);
    alert(viewName.Vehicles);
    var v1 = new Array(viewName.Vehicles);
    for (var i=0; i < v1.length;++i){
        alert("");
        addOption(document.myform1.v1, v1[i], v1[i]);
        }

function addOption(selectbox,text,value )
{
    var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
    optn.text = text;
    optn.value = value;
    selectbox.options.add(optn);
}
```

I am getting the values of

> alert(viewName.Vehicles);

as v123,v234,v345. But I need to convert var veh as ArrayList  to pass to the selectbox

The code to convert it to ArrayList is not working.

Comment: What you want do actully as v1 is an array already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you parse the your json, `viewName.Vehicles` is already an array.

```
for (var i=0; i < viewName.Vehicles.length;++i){
    addOption(document.myform1[viewName.Vehicles[i]], viewName.Vehicles[i], viewName.Vehicles[i]);
}
```

you can check it like:

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(viewName.Vehicles)
```

the result is:

```
"[object Array]"
```

or try:

```
viewName.Vehicles instanceof Array
```

Comment: but when i pass addOption(document.myform1.viewName.Vehicles, viewName.Vehicles[i], viewName.Vehicles[i]); It fails..

Comment: @user2093576: I think what you want to do is `document.myform1[viewName.Vehicles[i]]`

Comment: @user2093576: are these your field names "v123" , "v345" , "v567" ?

Comment: values of the key - "Vehicles" : [ "v123" , "v345" , "v567"]

Comment: You were absolutely right..  addOption(document.myform1.Vehicle_list, viewName.Vehicles[i], viewName.Vehicles[i]);   working fine